Excel to join columns from another worksheet by matching text of another column
I have names in SheetA I want to copy into copy into a names column in SheetB for records matching an overlap in product name that appears in both worksheets. Basically, I want to add  column data into a sheet by matching another column.
For example in SheetA we have:

So, is there a formula or wizard for this?

XLOOKUP, VLOOKUP, INDEX/MATCH....
